# else if and elif not working for my python code

Tags: python

This is my first day of learning to code. I tried this code and do not know why did it fail. Any help is much appreciated:

```
a=int(input())

if a>10:
    print("your number is greater than 10")
    else:
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: 1) Your indentation is wrong (the `else:` shouldn't be indented) 2) You need a statement after the `else:`, you can't just leave it blank.

Comment: fix the indentation..

Comment: You put an `else:` with no statement also you need to indent the `print` statement

Comment: If you're using python 3, your next issue will be that `a` will be a string not an integer

Comment: good luck - make sure you are using a good code editor as this can really help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

```
if a>10:
    print("your number is greater than 10") #indent the print statement
else:
    print('Not greater than 10')
    #you need to perform an action inside the else condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect. It should look like the following:

```
a=input()
if a>10:
    print("your number is greater than 10")
else:
    # You didn't have anything in your else statement so either remove it or add a statement...
    print("your number is <= 10")
```

See the [python documentation on indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error:

```
if condition:  
    code...  
elif condition:  
    another code...  
else:  
    last code...
```

Where the `elif` and `else` parts are optional, and `elif` means `else: if condition:`.

PS: Use `int(input())` otherwise you would get an string but no an int.

Answer (score 0):

using control-j and control-left-bracket to indent, and control-right-bracket to dedent will give you back control of the indentation.  When you type lines into the interpreter, it mis-manages the indentation.  It is up to you to make it right.

So, the informal tutorial that you are following needs updating.
It may have "worked" for older versions of Python.
Making it work for all of them would be a task, since there have been
changes to the language of the years.

Answer (score -1):

Brother,
Indentation is very important in Python. Since else: is another Conditional Expression, it should be independent of any other Conditional Expression. Hence, it has to be placed outside the indent of the if a>10:, and should have a statement inside it, that will be executed upon fulfillment of the above condition it is part of.
Thus, the correct code is:-

```
a=int(input())

if a>10:
    print("your number is greater than 10")

else:
    print("your number is not greater than 10")
```

Comment: This solution was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283553/18145256).